# Will a polled event system cause lag for a server?

Tags: c++, game-design

I'm using a library called ENet. It is a reliable UDP library.

The way it works is a polled event system like this:

```
  ENetEvent event;

    /* Wait up to 1000 milliseconds for an event. */
    while (enet_host_service (client, & event, 1000) > 0)
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_CONNECT:
            printf ("A new client connected from %x:%u.\n", 
                    event.peer -> address.host,
                    event.peer -> address.port);

            /* Store any relevant client information here. */
            event.peer -> data = "Client information";

            break;

        case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_RECEIVE:
            printf ("A packet of length %u containing %s was received from %s on channel %u.\n",
                    event.packet -> dataLength,
                    event.packet -> data,
                    event.peer -> data,
                    event.channelID);

            /* Clean up the packet now that we're done using it. */
            enet_packet_destroy (event.packet);

            break;

        case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_DISCONNECT:
            printf ("%s disconected.\n", event.peer -> data);

            /* Reset the peer's client information. */

            event.peer -> data = NULL;
        }
    }
```

It waits up to 1000 milliseconds for an event. If I'm hosting say 75 event driven card games and a lobby on the same thread as this code, will it cause any problems.

If my understanding is correct, the process will simply sleep until there is an event, when there is one, it will process the event then come back here where potentially 5 or so events have queued up since so enet_host_services would return right away and not cause lag.

I have been advised not to use multiple threads, will that be alright like this?

Thanks

Comment: Reliable UDP? That's almost certainly the wrong choice for what you intend to do. You most likely just want to use TCP.

Comment: If you aren't using multiple threads, and `enet_host_service` is a blocking operation, then the server will freeze for up to 1000ms constantly.

Comment: @lohiris: while that may be true for this project, there note that "reliable udp" and tcp are not the same things.  Tcp is a single channel ordered guaranteed protocol, while udp can be used to implement multi-channel communications where each channel may be ordered and/or guaranteed independently, which is what energy does.  Also, even just reimplemenrting tcp in udp has a few advantages, such as being able to work with a stun server for p2p connections behind firewalls without upnp support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entire game is driven by events that come in via `enet_host_service`, then no, you won't get any delays as a result of this approach. The server may keep sleeping for 1 second but nothing is happening in that period so it doesn't matter.

If however you have any other timed action which happens regardless of which events come in, then they will presumably live outside that switch statement and will have to wait for external events to trigger before the action can execute.

If you are in that situation and do have some other timed events, you can always reduce that 1000ms delay to something smaller, like 50ms, so that the timed events can be attended to fairly regularly. This is unlikely to have a significant negative effect on performance.

Note that you need to wrap the above code in another loop, as `enet_host_service` will return zero as soon as it manages to go an entire second without getting a message.

Comment: Or just put the event polling in another thread, and it will consume very little of the cpu because of the "sleeps" in the blocking call, and the main thread will be full speed.

Comment: True, but that just moves the problem - you still have to get the messages back to and from the network thread, which is non-trivial to do correctly. I guess this is why the original poster stated, "I have been advised not to use multiple threads".

Comment: Fair enough, then I would suggest to make an intermediate buffer to post/read the packets received. A mutex would solve any syncronization issues, and the first problem would be addressed too :)